# Mostrar 4 item cada vez que se ejecute la paginacion automatica

Tags: carrusel, owl

actualmente tengo un carousel con owl-carousel y tengo activo el loop infinito, pero cada paginacion solo muestra un item nuevo y no 4 como veo que lo hace cuando quito el loop y lo dejo con los botones de navegacion, hay alguna forma de cambiar esto?

Estoy usando el codigo de ejemplo que ellos tienen como demo en su web que es

```
owl.owlCarousel({
   items:4,
   loop:true,
   margin:10,
   autoplay:true,
   autoplayTimeout:1000,
   autoplayHoverPause:true
});
```

Comment: No es que sepa, pero en la documentación le entregan la cantidad de ítems en responisve dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla. [link](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html)

Comment: Además estan llamando diferente al owl de como lo tienes tu.